# how do i create a python script to run a jenkins job?

Tags: python, jenkins

I am working on a python script that will go and trigger a Jenkins job - the purpose of this job is to run a simple selenium script

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: the problem is I am not able to find the right reference to the python code which will execute the script from my git repo. Config wise i could able to set it up

Comment: "The right reference" -  what does that mean? Please provide details. This is still very vague.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the jenkins api: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/

The docs show you how to do it like this

```
curl JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters \
  --user USER:TOKEN \
  --data id=123 --data verbosity=high
```

but you can make those kinds of calls with python too.

There are also python client libraries for this, but that might not be necessary.

You can make a python http request with either `httplib` or with `requests` https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/index.html if you install it

Comment: I would start by getting the correct curl call, and try to make a python script make the same call.. or just write a bash script instead and use curl... unless you are using windows... in which case, I don't know how that works